# Approx Solution Question

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that the subspace T of R^4 is described by the equations

```
 x1 - x2  + 2x3 + x4 = 0
2x1 - x2        - x4 = 0
3x1 - 2x2 + 2x3      = 0
```

Find the point in T which is closest to the point (0,0,0,1). You don't have to finish the work, but you must give an expression from which the point can easily be computed.

- I know I have to find the basis for the subspace in order for projection to work
- Row echelon form is

  1  -1  2  1

  0   1 -4 -3

  0   0  0  0

Comment: First of all, that matrix is row echelon form, but not **reduced** row echelon form.  Second, what's the problem?  Do you know how to find the basis of the null space of a matrix?

Comment: I think yoy mean "Find the point **IN** T which is closest to the point (0,0,0,1)", right?

Comment: you are correct candyman

Comment: the null space has a basis (2,4,1,0) ,(2,3,0,1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find a basis of the nullspace of that matrix to be $\{(2,4,1,0),(2,3,0,1)\}$, which means that this is a basis for $T$.  If we set 
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&2\\4&3\\1&0\\0&1}
$$
then the projection of the vector $b = (0,0,0,1)$ onto $T$ is the solution to the equation $A^TAx = A^Tb$.